# Electric Throttle Body Volvo S70 2000

Tags: volvo, o2-sensor

So I had my volvo brought in to replace the o2 sensor so I could get my emissions done. (Car ran completely fine). After picking it up, it ran fine to my house. The following day, when I turned the engine over, it shook really hard, puttered at 1 at idle, and I could not get the car to go above 25mph. When I returned to the shop, they plugged the OBD in and it threw a whole bunch of codes, when the kid hit "clear", the car instantly died. Battery is now dead, and they are saying the Electrc Throttle Body needs to be replaced. (Called it a freak thing and unrelated to the o2 sensor being replaced). Anyone have any input, please.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you get the codes? I doubt the TB and O2 replacement are related, but the battery dying at the same time? That's pretty weird.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Volvo community, this is a common issue.

https://www.matthewsvolvosite.com/volvos-electronic-throttle-module-fiasco